# Check whether user is reached to required latlong or not by using current position of user on map android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I am implementing navigation screen using Google direction API on Google map v2 in android. Here user will be in driving and I have to show the turn by turn information to the user based on his current position.

So I would like to find whether user has reached the required position(LatLng) or not. If he reached I have to show information on screen.

For this, How can I calculate whether user has reached the required location(LatLng) or not using his current location? 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise [geofencing api](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) to set a geofence centered at the `required position(LatLng)` and with a radius based on how much time before reaching the actual point, you need an alert and to compensate for any location inaccuracy.